# Keep a SpriteKit scene running while Control/Notification Center Open

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm currently working on a simple multiplayer game using Xcode, Swift and SpriteKit.

Everything is going well until the user opens the Control/Notification Center by swiping down from the top of the screen or up from the bottom of the screen. At that point, the scene pauses until the user closes the Control/Notification Center.

I'm hoping there is a way to keep said `SKScene` running while it is open. If it's not possible, perhaps there is a way

- to prevent the Notification/Control center from opening while in the SKScene, or
- to detect when a player opens the center as a delegate method?

Of course, the title of this question asks about keeping an `SKScene` running, not preventing/detecting a Notification/Control center interference. The items listed above are just potential ideas in case this question has no viable solution.

I'm running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on a 2017 MacBookPro. I'm also in Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a). Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to grab the notification that causes your scene to pause, and prevent it from pausing (or unpause after),  I do bot remember offhand which notification fires.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That turns out to be, interestingly enough, `applicationDidEnterBackground`. Not sure how I will prevent the scene from pausing, however, as the scene pauses automatically when entering the background.